# Access VBA, open several instances of the same report at the same time

Tags: ms-access, vba

From a form, I'm aiming at opening several instances of a report with only a change of the Id's being shown.

So, the VBA code is:

```
    DoCmd.OpenReport "ordentallerSobre", acViewPreview, , "id = 20370"
    DoCmd.OpenReport "ordentallerSobre", acViewPreview, , "id = 20371"
```

And then, only the last report is shown as a tab. But I need to show both of them. Any solution to this apparently trivial issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the 'Distinct' clause.  A couple weeks ago I had to export items from a table, and save each as a seperate CSV file.  I would see your issue as this.  Below is my working code.  I hope it helps you.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command0_Click()

Dim dbThis As Database
Dim rsThis As Recordset
Dim qdfNew As QueryDef

Set dbThis = CurrentDb()

Set rsThis = dbThis.OpenRecordset("Select Distinct OrderID as dValue from Orders where OrderID is not null", dbOpenSnapshot)

Do While Not rsThis.EOF
    Debug.Print rsThis.Fields("dValue").Value
    Set qdfNew = New QueryDef

    ' Don't use quotes if you are filtering on a numeric field
    qdfNew.SQL = "select * from Orders where OrderID = " & rsThis.Fields("dValue").Value & ""

    ' Use quotes around the variable if you are filtering on a text field
    ' qdfNew.SQL = "select * from Orders where OrderID = '" & rsThis.Fields("dValue").Value & "'"

    qdfNew.Name = "qryTemp"
    dbThis.QueryDefs.Delete "qryTemp"
    dbThis.QueryDefs.Append qdfNew
    qryTemp = qdfNew.SQL
    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "qryTemp", "C:\Test\" & rsThis.Fields("dValue").Value & ".csv", True
    rsThis.MoveNext
Loop
rsThis.Close

End Sub
```

With a slight modification, you should be able to make it work for your report.

Comment: Thanks! Good one!

Answer (score 5):

This is not-so-trivial. Reports, forms and queries, by default, only support one instance.

My approach is the following:

In the report, add a single line at the top (after `Option Explicit`):

```
Public Myself As Object
```

Then, instead of your current code, use the following:

```
Dim rpt As Report_ordentallerSobre
Set rpt = New Report_ordentallerSobre
Set rpt.Myself = rpt
rpt.Filter = "id = 20370"
rpt.FilterOn = True
rpt.Visible = True
Set rpt = New Report_ordentallerSobre
Set rpt.Myself = rpt
rpt.Filter = "id = 20371"
rpt.FilterOn = True
rpt.Visible = True
```

This opens two reports with two different filters.

Note that they are both opened in their default view, this can't be changed. Also, there are several difficulties with such objects, such as the fact that you can't specify the instance of the report in the `Reports` collection or using several `DoCmd` statements.

[Allen Browne](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-35.html) has an article about multi-instance forms which is about the same as reports. His approach is somewhat more complex than this one, but more simple than the one I actually use (that involves a predeclared object that manages these multi-instance forms)